# Remove the ending of a column in pandas dataframe starting from a specific substring

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df with only one column which have strings like: 005f12b33ac4bdb310d8e503a065ef10b28566ea#code_id#alarm|clock

I want to remove the ending of the string starting from #code_id# and want the string to look like
005f12b33ac4bdb310d8e503a065ef10b28566ea

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
df['Column_name']= df['Column_name'].astype(str).str.split('#').str[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract('(.*)#code_id#')
```